# Unable to test credit card in PayPal sandbox using "Pay with a debit or credit card" option

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am unable to test a purchase using a credit card in PayPal sandbox using "Pay with a debit or credit card" option.  I am using the current version of Chrome in an incognito window using a Windows 10 VM, 4111111111111111 as the test VISA card (from https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm), 01/19 as the Exp date, 123 as the CSC, and fake customer info generated randomly.  Every time I click the Pay button, I receive the error message "You might already have an account, Please login."  I have repeatedly cleared all info in the browser and cache and used a new VM, but no change.
I did not have this issue a few months ago (last time I tested), when I was able to use several test card numbers successfully in sandbox.
What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Only credit cards issued to a PayPal buyer (personal) account will work now. Cards issued by random number generators do not appear to work, unless someone else has a answer to this...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just generate any test credit card from a card-generator site like http://credit-card-generator.2-ee.com/ and use that card. Hopefully it should work.